# Fill a Textbox with a Link?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, internet-explorer, firefox

i have a link and i want to prepare it so that i fill a textbox with a value.
This is the link http://www.lolking.net/ and i want that if a always go to this site they fill the texbox where is write ("Summore name..."). 
How i can make this? Must be write a script for the site ? Or can i prepare link to fill this textbox?

This question is for all site where is a textbox, i get the name of the textbox with F12 and i want to prepare all links how i fill textbox

Greetz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could reasonably write a Chrome extension which does this. You'd have to add logic for each site that you want it to work on, but actually replacing the text in that box (I assume that you want it to automatically search for your summoner name) is as simple as this one line:

```
document.getElementsByName("name")[0].value="<YOUR SUMMONER NAME>";
```

But that example will only work on lolking.net. To make it more general, you would replace "name" in the following way:

```
document.getElementsById("<INPUT ID>")[0].value="<REPLACEMENT TEXT>";
```